# ASP.NET MVC Controller won't catch exceptions from LINQ lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, exception

I have a bog-standard MVC Controller with a try/catch around the code to be able to return some custom data if an exception occurs. This works just fine for exceptions thrown directly in the controller, or directly in methods used by the controller. But if an exception is thrown inside a LINQ lambda the exception is not caught at all and the Yellow Screen Of Death (YSOD) is displayed instead.

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    public JsonResult Index() {
        try {
            var data = new TestService().GetTestData();
            return Json(data.Entries.Select(d => d.SomeExtensionMethod(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return Json("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

If I throw an exception manually inside the try/catch then "Something went wrong" is returned. If an exception is thrown inside `GetTestData()` then "Something went wrong" is returned.

If `d.SomeExtensionMethod()` throws an exception, then a YSOD is displayed.

Why are exceptions inside the LINQ lambda not caught by the try/catch, and what can I do to actually catch it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't evaluated immediately:

```
data.Entries.Select(d => d.SomeExtensionMethod())
```

It creates an expression tree which can be evaluated later.  This allows multiple operations to be chained (calls to `.Where()`, `.OrderBy()`, `.GroupBy()`, etc.) into one larger expression tree so that it's only executed against the backing data source once.

Because when that backing data source is a database, you don't want to immediately materialize the entire table and then perform the filtering/sorting/etc. in code but rather want to build the entire query in code and then execute it once against the highly optimized database engine.

What that means in this case is that the expression tree, not the resulting data, is passed along the pipeline in the framework and some later framework-internal operation is finally invoking that expression tree to materialize the results, and *that* is when the exception occurs.  After this controller method has already returned.

*For this particular case* you can probably safely get away with forcing the code to evaluate the expression tree and materialize the results right away.  A simple way to do this is with `.ToList()`:

```
data.Entries.Select(d => d.SomeExtensionMethod()).ToList()
```

It shouldn't make a difference in this case because you're not going to make any more changes to that expression tree and it's about to be evaluated by the framework anyway.

**However**, note that this approach is not a drop-in solution in all such cases.  Any individual instance of these queries would need to be examined for how forcing the query to materialize results might affect the performance.  For example, suppose a simple `.Select()` result is passed to a view, but then within the view itself more operations are appended to that result.  If the controller added `.ToList()` then those operations would be performed on the entire in-memory set, not against the database.

If the view has something like `.Take(10)` then the intent would have been to only fetch the first ten records from the database, but appending `.ToList()` early in the process means that it's now fetching *all* records from the database (hundreds? millions? more?) and then just displaying the first ten.  You can see where this might cause performance issues.

Since in the code shown the intent is to return all of the records then no harm is done in forcing the system to fetch all of the records a moment earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation. I already knew about the execution plan for LINQ, but I just didn't think about there being scaffolding around my code that would execute it outside my method. Adding a `.ToList()` works just perfectly, of course :)